# Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::confirm() laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel5

почему выбило эту ошибку?

```
BadMethodCallException
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::confirm()
```

в контроллере:

```
  public function confirm(User $user, $token)
    {
        $userToken = User::where('email', $user->email)->where('confirmation_token', $token);

        if (! $userToken){
            return redirect()->route('send-email-confirmation', $user);
        }

        $userToken->confirm();
        return redirect('profile');
    }
```

в User.php

```
public function confirm()
    {
        $this->update([
            'is_confirm' => true,
            'confirmation_token' => null
        ]);

        return $this;
    }
```

Comment: `User::where([
  'email' => $user->email, 
  'confirmation_token' => $token
])->first()`

Comment: а так как я написал нельзя?

Comment: Вам нужно чтобы выполнить first чтобы вернуло 
Model или null, иначе вы работаете с Query\Builder

Answer (score 1):

В конце запроса на получение токена нужно дописать `->first()`

Получится:

```
$userToken = User::where('email', $user->email)->where('confirmation_token', $token)->first();
```